# Is PHP faster than Nginx/Apache to check file exist?

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I need to check the availability of a file on the server and then doing some reaction related to the file. I have the file name and path in each client and server side, then I have two ways to check the availability. One from the client side and another one from the server side.

### First way:

Client side:

```
function check_file()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.example.com/somefile.txt',
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function()
        {
            //file not exists
            //check again after 5 seconds
            setTimeout(function(){
                check_file();
            }, 5000);
        },
        success: function()
        {
            //file exists
            //start doing other actions related to the file
            action_1();
        }
    });
}

function action_1()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.example.com/action_1.php',
        success: function(data)
        {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (result.success)
            {
                //Changes were applied successfully.
                //doing some DOM stuff and notifying the client

                //check again after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function(){
                    check_file();
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Server side (action_1.php):

```
//update database
echo '{success: true}';
```

### Second way:

Client side:

```
function action_2()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.example.com/action_2.php',
        success: function(data)
        {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (result.success)
            {
                //Changes were applied successfully
                //doing some DOM stuff and notifying the client
            }

            setTimeout(function(){
                action_2();
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Server side (action_2.php):

```
if (file_exists('somefile.txt'))
{
    //update database
    echo '{success: true}';
}
else
{
    echo '{success: false}';
}
```

In the first way, I am calling the server twice (**`Request`**/`Response`/**`Request`**, please note first request is only requesting for the `HEAD`), and it is using `Apache's` default scenario to check the file availability (that I don't know how it is working).


But in the second way, I am calling the server once, and it is using the `PHP file_exists()` that it mean it need to load `PHP environment` first, then execute `action_2.php`.

Because the file is not mostly existent and because it need to handle maybe millions of requests, Then can you please guide me which way is better and why?

Comment: I'm a little confused: why not just call the URL you want to call, with the data that needs to go there, and then if you get an HTTP response that doesn't have status code 200, do whatever you need to do because that URL doesn't exist (404) or the user doesn't have access (403) or the file was moved (304/307) or the request itself had errors (400) etc? The client should not have to ask the server whether _files_ exist, it should only call URLs, and the server should be able to tell the client whether that worked, or why it didn't. And then the client should handle that information sensibly.

Comment: What do you do on success? are you sending another HTTP request? if so, go for the PHP way and instead of returning `{success: true}` and then sending another request, do the action in the same request. If it's just a client side thing that you do depending if that file exists, then theoretically the 1st way will be faster (but not significantly). You can always test it for yourself. One more note: if you go with the 1st way don't forget to disable caching for that file.

Comment: I could not understand your comment @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. Why the client should not have to ask the server whether files exist?

Comment: @HTMHell on success, I will do some DOM stuff and then requesting again. I have updated too.

Comment: Because the client should not know anything about the filesystem on your server. All it should care about is API end points. "Update file X with content Y" should only be something your client can call if either the page loaded from the server with a state that indicates the file exists, or a previous client operation (e.g. an upload) comes with a response that the file now exists. In the absence of more details on why this is how your client/server interact, this is kind of an antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

First way is faster for sure, especially if there is Nginx on server instead of Apache,  but you must ensure that your fetching "somefile.txt" is not cached in any way.

Both, your browser and web server likes to cache static files.

Answer (score 0):

While the first way is probably faster, presuming that in most cases the file does not exist, I'd go with the second way.

The first way is faster than the second way as it does not call the PHP handler but just the default static file handler. I didn't tested that, but I'd assume that checking if a file exists and returning an error (404) of some kind should be noticeable faster than calling the PHP interpreter, which then executes the PHP file.

However, the second way is IMO much more cleaner and better understandable than the first way, offering a better concentration of the "file checking" logic which is spread over server & client in the first way.